# ef-core load collection property of nested tph inherited member

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, tph

Given the following class structure

```
 public class Parent 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; 
        public List<BaseChild> Children { get; set; }
    }

 public abstract class BaseChild
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ChildName { get; set; }
    }

public class NormalChild : BaseChild
    {
         public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

public class RichChild : BaseChild
    {
        public List<OffshoreAccount> OffshoreAccounts { get; set; }
    }

public class OffshoreAccount 
    {
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public AccountInfo AccountInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

What is the best way to query parent data to include information about the children's offshore accounts?. I came up with the solution below, using ef-core's explicit loading, but it just doesn't feel right. Is there a more elegant solution?

```
var parent = Context.Set<Parent>()
    .Where(o => o.Id == Guid.Parse(parentId))
    .Include(o => o.Children)
    .SingleOrDefault();

foreach (var child in parent.Children.OfType<RichChild>())
    {
        Context.Entry<RichChild>(child).Collection(f => f.OffshoreAccounts).Load();
        foreach (var account in child.OffshoreAccounts)
            {
                 Context.Entry<OffshoreAccount>(account).Reference(f => f.AccountInfo).Load();
            }
     }
```

Comment: Please please rename `childs` to `children`.

Comment: What is `AccountInfo`?

Comment: To avoid that code overhead for loading the related entities you should let EF do that job by either enabling EF lazy loading or eager loading. Look here for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @Felix There is no lazy loading in EF Core currently, and also no syntax for eager loading derived class properties.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update (EF Core 2.1+):**

Starting with v2.1, EF Core native supports [Include on derived types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#include-on-derived-types) through C# cast or `as` operators.

e.g

```
.Include(e => e.Children)
    .ThenInclude(e => ((RichChild)e).OffshoreAccounts)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.AccountInfo)
```

or

```
.Include(e => e.Children)
    .ThenInclude(e => (e as RichChild).OffshoreAccounts)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.AccountInfo)
```

The documentation claims that the `string` overload of `Include` coudld also be used, e.g. according to it

```
.Include(e => "Children.OffshoreAccounts.AccountInfo")
```

should also work, but it doesn't (checked up to v3.1.4).

**Original:**

Currently there is no way to accomplish that in the parent query, but the explicit loading can be improved by using a combination of `Entry`, `Collection`, `Query`, `Include` / `ThenInclude` and `Load` calls:

```
var parent = Context.Set<Parent>()
    .Where(o => o.Id == Guid.Parse(parentId))
    .Include(o => o.Children)
    .SingleOrDefault();

Context.Entry(parent).Collection(e => e.Children)
    .Query().OfType<RichChild>()
    .Include(e => e.OffshoreAccounts)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.AccountInfo)
    .Load();
```

Comment: How can I expand this to a further down tph?
To give context I have the following structure (working on a form builder):
Form.Questions.Control
With control being the basetype for classes such as dropdown or TextField.

Comment: @Peter-Paul So you want to include parts of Control? I can't say exactly - since the above is some sort of a hack, hence no generically extendable, you might consider posting your own concrete question with sample [mcve].

Comment: I eventually did it by first getting the form, then looping over the questions to add the class specific properties control by control.
Lots of database calls, but it got the job done.

Comment: @IvanStoev Have you got a github issue link or doc that mentions this?

Comment: @Dealdiane [#3910](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3910)

Answer (score 13):

In the current EFCore (2.1.1) you can use type casting in `ThenInclude` to get the results you're looking for:

```
var parent = _context.Set<Parent>()
                 .Include(x => x.Children)
                 .ThenInclude(y => (y as RichChild).OffshoreAccounts)
                 .SingleOrDefault();
```